# Jquery modal select issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal window with a select inside.
The modal works fine, but the select works only once.
What is the problem?

This is my js.

```
$s = jQuery.noConflict();
$s(document).ready(function() {

 //Display the modal
 $s('#att-add').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $s.fn.custombox( this, {
        overlay: true,
        effect: 'fadein',
        eClose: '.close'
    });
    $s('select').selectric();
 });
});
```

For the select box i'm using Selectric.

This is my html for modal window

```
  <div id="modal" style="display: none;" class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" title="inchide">&times;</button>
        <h3>Adauga un atribut nou</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Numele atributului</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" atocomplete="off" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Selectati grupul de atribute</label>
        <select name="groups" class="select">
          {section name=op loop=$groups.attribute_group_id}
           <option value="{$groups.attribute_group_id[op]}">{$groups.name[op]}</option>
           {/section}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Ordinea</label>
        <input class="ordine" type="text" name="ordine"/>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say "select works only once", do you mean selectric only gets applied the first time you open the modal? Then when you close the modal and open it again, it isn't applied? Are you getting any errors in the console? Can you include your HTML?

Comment: Are you using templating? Is the problem that the templating is not working, or the selectric styling is not being applied?

Comment: I'm using smarty, the problem appears when the modal is closing first time

Comment: Okay, so what is the problem? What is actually happening? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: if i put $s('select').selectric(); outside the click function it doesent work at all.

Comment: I want the select to work every time i open the modal window :P

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you unless you clarify what is not working.

Comment: I have multiple inputs and a select option in a modal window. When the modal is opening for the first time the select option works.If i close the modal window, the select is somehow disabled..not clickable or something like that.If i refresh the page and open the modal, the select its working again for the first modal opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that when `selectric` applies its styling, it removes the `select` element and the templating inside it. What you might need to do is pass a callback to the `close` property of `custombox` to destroy `selectric` when the user closes the modal:

```
$s = jQuery.noConflict();
$s(document).ready(function() {

     //Display the modal
     $s('#att-add').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $s.fn.custombox( this, {
            overlay: true,
            effect: 'fadein',
            eClose: '.close',
            close: function () { $s('select').selectric('destroy'); }
        });
        $s('select').selectric();
     });
});
```

This is untested, I'm unable to easily recreate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Selectric but I'm guessing it's probably because you are initializing the same select on every click. Try moving the `$s('select').selectric();` line outside the click function.

```
    $s = jQuery.noConflict();
    $s(document).ready(function() {

    $s('select').selectric();

     //Display the modal
     $s('#att-add').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $s.fn.custombox( this, {
            overlay: true,
            effect: 'fadein',
            eClose: '.close'
        });
     });
    });
```